# Multiple Regression, 'Predict' Independent variable?

Tags: multiple-regression

I read that it is possible to use the multiple regression, and to interpret that we can predict the dependent variable using the historical independent variables.
Y(t+1) = a*X_1(t) + b*X_2(t) + e(t)

Is it also possible to use the multiple regression in this case??
Y(t-1) = a*X_1(t) + b*X_2(t) + e(t)

Can I interpret the result like this??

'The historical value of the dependent variable is related to the present value of the independent variables. And if we know the historical value of the dependent variable, We know that the independent variables are changed by (a,b)'

Comment: Independent variables are exogenous according to multiple regression assumption. So you can't make any conclusions about your independent variables using information concerning dependent variable.

Comment: @Bogdan Thank you for the comment. Did you mean that this form of regression is impossible? Y(t-1)=a*X_1(t) + b*X_2(t) +e(t).
      [Y(t), X_1(t) and X_2(t) are time series]

Comment: This form of regression is possible, but its interpretation will undermine that the past depends on future. So I hardly imagine any theory that may work this way. However, if someone find some theory that will met such a regression form, I think he deserves nobel prize or something like that). The only think I can imagine is that $x_{t}=f_{x}(z_{t-1})$ and $y_{t}=f_{y}(z_{t})+e_{t}$ so both **x** and **y** are functions of some unobservable variable **z**. And if you what to find some ommited values of **y** in the past, but you don't know z, then you may construct a model you suggested.